# Regression model prediction in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, regression, linear-regression

I have encountered a problem when writing a regression prediction in R shiny. It says it cannot find the object "studytime" from the dataset but when I tried the same regression code in standard form, it can work out. The error is shown as the figure below.

Could you please help me fix it? Thanks very much!

```
library(shiny)

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00356/student.zip",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "student-mat.csv")
mathdat <- read.table("student-mat.csv",sep= ";", header= T)
unlink(temp)
#(math <- as_tibble(math))

# Define UI for Predicting MPG of a car,display summary,table and plot using  mtcars dataset with tabs
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  # Application title
  headerPanel("Linear Regression Analysis"),
  
  # Adding widgets
  sidebarPanel(
    h4("Help text"),
    helpText("Enter the First Grade , the Second Grade and Study Time,
             click on ",strong("Predict!")," to get predicted value of final grade."),
    numericInput("G1", label = "the First Grade",value = 10, min = 3, max = 19),
    helpText("The range of the first grade is from 3 to 19 points."),
    br(),
    radioButtons("sex", label = "Gender",list("Female" = 0,"Male" = 1),"0"),
    sliderInput("G2", label = "the Second Grade", 
                value = 10, min = 0, max = 19, animate=T),
    helpText("The range of the second grade is from 0 to 19 points."),
    actionButton("actionButton","Predict!",align = "center"),
    helpText("Note : for ",strong("Summary,Plot"), " and",
             strong("Table")," whole",strong("math"),
             "dataset is taken into account and results are displayed respectively.")
    
  ),
  
  # Show a tabset that includes mpg prediction, plot, summary, and table view of mtcars dataset
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Prediction",
               h2("Multiple Regression Predction ",align="center") ,
               p("A multiple linear regression (MLR) model that describes a ",
                 strong("dependent variable y by independent variables x1, x2, ..., xp with error.")), 
               p("For example, the dataset from UCI Machine Learning Repository",
               strong("Studenet Performance")," 
               from records of the final grade for students from two Portuguese schools  . 
                 First Transform the dataset (higher, activities, schoolsup, famsup 
               and paid as factor variables).",
                 strong("lm")," is 
                 ", strong("used to fit linear model")," 
                 by taking some other dependent variables into account. 
               (traveltime, studytime, freetime, goout, )Choose a",
                 strong("model by AIC in a stepwise Algorithm"),
                 "The obtained model has 3 (G1, G2, sex) independent variables.") ,
               h3("Predction Interval for the Final Grade"),
               
               p("We now apply the predict function and 
                 set the predictor variable in the newdata argument. 
                 We also set the interval type as",
                 strong("predict")," and use",
                 strong(" the default 0.95 confidence level")),
               
               p("The predicted",span("the Final Grade",style = "color:blue")," 
                 and its",span(" Lower Bound",style="color:blue"),"and",
                 span("Upper Bound",style="color:blue")," values are :"),
               
               code(textOutput("final"))
      ),
      
      tabPanel("Summary", 
               h2("Summary of",strong("math"),"dataset"),
               verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
      tabPanel("Table", 
               h2("Generate an HTML table view of math dataset"),
               tableOutput("table")),
      tabPanel("Diagnostic Plots" ,
               h2("Diagnostic plots provide checks for heteroscedasticity, 
                  normality, and influential observerations."),
               plotOutput("myplot"))
    )
  )
))

library(shiny)

# Read the data
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00356/student.zip",temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "student-mat.csv")
mathdat <- read.table("student-mat.csv",sep= ";", header= T)
unlink(temp)
#(math <- as_tibble(math))

# transforming into factor variables
mathdat$higher <- as.factor(mathdat$higher)
mathdat$activities <- as.factor(mathdat$activities)
mathdat$schoolsup <- as.factor(mathdat$schoolsup)
mathdat$paid <- as.factor(mathdat$paid)
mathdat$sex <- as.factor(mathdat$sex)

# math structure after tranformation 
str(mathdat)

# fitting linear model
model <- lm(G3 ~ G1 + G2 + traveltime + studytime + freetime + goout + absences + famrel +
              higher + activities + schoolsup + paid, data = mathdat )

# Choose a model by AIC in a Stepwise Algorithm
best_model <- step(model, direction="both")

# generate model summary
summary(best_model)

# Define server logic for this application
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to predict the mpg. This is 
  # called whenever the inputs change. The renderers defined 
  # below then all use the value computed from this expression
  output$sex <- renderText({ input$sex })
  
  output$final <- renderText({ 
    input$actionButton
    isolate({
      # G1 , G2, sex
      newdata = data.frame(G1 = G1(), G2 = input$G2, sex = input$sex)
      final  <- predict(best_model,newdata , interval = "predict")
    })
  })
  
  
  # Generate diagnostic plot s
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    # optional 4 graphs/page
    layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),2,2,byrow=T))
    plot(model)
    
  })
  G1 <- reactive({
    first <- as.numeric(input$G1)
  })
  
  # Generate a summary of the data
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(mathdat)
  })
  
  # Generate an HTML table view of the data
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(mathdat)
  })
})
```

[image]

Comment: make sure your dataset `mathdat ` has studytime. You can add a `print(head(mathdat))` in your code before modeling and check the content of the dataframe in console.

Comment: Make sure to save your app in `app.R` and use `runApp` to get a traceback of your error, see [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#debugging)

Comment: Could you try to limit your code to the error section? You'll have a much larger chance to get a solution if your code is easily reproducible and does not contain irrelevant code for solving your problem